# OkHttp load signed certificate

Tags: java, okhttp

I need to emulate client api requests for testing purposes. Our server now uses https and I was recommended to use OkHttpClient instead of our original BaseHttpClient implementation. I have found that I need to add `.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, x509TrustManager)` to my client builder and I also found helpful code to load a certificate:

```
private X509TrustManager trustManagerForCertificates(InputStream in)
{
    CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    Collection<? extends Certificate> certificates = certificateFactory.generateCertificates(in);
    char[] password = "password".toCharArray(); // Any password will work.
    KeyStore keyStore = newEmptyKeyStore(password);
    int index = 0;
    for (Certificate certificate : certificates) {
      String certificateAlias = Integer.toString(index++);
      keyStore.setCertificateEntry(certificateAlias, certificate);
    }
    KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, password);
    TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);
    return (X509TrustManager) trustManagers[0];
}
```

My issue is that my certificate has a key and I can't find a way to provide the contents of the `.crt` and `.key` files as a pair. If I were to curl it, I could do

```
curl --tlsv1.2 --insecure -v --key ./client.key --cert ./client.crt  https://myserver/api/request
```

Is there a way to do something similar with OkHttp? Or do i have to generate a new certificate using the existing one and its key?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I managed to get this to work using code from [this site](https://gist.github.com/rohanag12/07ab7eb22556244e9698), using [BouncyCastle](http://bouncycastle.org/)'s libraries.

To get it working, I also needed the `ca.crt` (it's included in the example - the curl command can do without this thanks to the `--insecure` switch). A lot of the sites I went through lead me to think that I need to create a certificate chain using the `ca` and `client` certificates but as you can see from the linked code, the solution is to have two key stores: one for the CA, to be used for the `TrustManager` and one for the client certificate, to be used for the `KeyManager`. The `SSLContext` can then be initialised with these two.

The last hurdle I came across was an exception:

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.jcajce.JcaJceHelper`

This was due to more than one version of `bouncycastle` being imported from various sources. Making sure I used the correct versions of `bcprov` and  `bcpkix` solved this issue.